# Searching Json keys for matching object from array and push to table

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to search a JSON to retrieve objects which match an array and then push all this data to table. 
My array looks like this:

```
player_IDs: number[] = [ 1000, 1002, 1004 ]
```

And the JSON that I am searching looks like this:

```
{
    "allplayers": [
        {
            "Player_ID": "1004D",
            "End_Time": "2019-04-29 13:31:06"
        },
        {
            "Player_ID": "1000A",
            "End_Time": "2019-04-29 07:39:55"
        }
        {
            "Player_ID": "1002G", 
            "End_Time": "2019-04-30 09:02:21"
        }
        {
            "Player_ID": "1006B", 
            "End_Time": "2019-04-30 10:21:01"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the JSON there is other data for other players that I don't want to display because their ID is not in the array.

I am currently displaying the Player_IDs from the array in the HTML like this:

```
 <table id="tableContents">
    <tr>
      <th>PLayer ID</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let id of player_IDs">
      <td>00{{ id }}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

But in the column next to it I want to be able to display the matching end time. I can get the `End_Time` and log it to the console, but I am not sure how push it to the table so that the end time match up with the current Player_IDs in the table. Is there a way to do with `*ngFor`?

This is how I am getting the `End_Time` and logging it to the console:

```
this.player_IDs.forEach(function(value) {
   var id = value.toString()
   var index = playerdata.allplayers.filter(e => e.Player_ID.includes(id))
   if (index.length!=0) {
       console.log(index[0].End_Time)
   }
})
```

So, how do I push the `End_Time` to the table so that they are displayed with the corresponding Player_ID?

Side note: It does not matter what order the Player_IDs are displayed in.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) Once you've parsed it and are using it in your code, it's not JSON anymore. That is, if you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to show the corresponding `End_Time` on the table, right? On each td column, you can bind it to the respective properties, `Player_ID` and `End_Time`. This is how it will look like:

```
<table id="tableContents">
    <tr>
      <th>Player ID</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let player of data.allplayers">
      <td>{{ player.Player_ID }}</td>
      <td>{{ player.End_Time }}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I have made a [quick demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynzo9u?file=src/app/app.component.ts) over here.

Comment: I only want to display the data where the player id is in the array as well. So it should only display 3

Comment: @JackU yes I understand, you can use the same logic on the resulting array.

Comment: I can display the array in the table similar to how you've done it, but how do i filter down the "JSON" to only get the End Times of those in the array?

Comment: @JackU I have updated my demo such that it displays only the filtered Data. I have also made some adjustments to the code you have provided initially. You may refer to it on the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: As for your other question, what are you trying to achieve? You just want an array of that consists of only `End_Time `?

Answer (score 0):

```
        {
        "allplayers": [
            {
                "Player_ID": "1004D",
                "End_Time": "2019-04-29 13:31:06"
            },
            {
                "Player_ID": "1000A",
                "End_Time": "2019-04-29 07:39:55"
            },
            {
                "Player_ID": "1002G", 
                "End_Time": "2019-04-30 09:02:21"
            },
            {
                "Player_ID": "1006B", 
                "End_Time": "2019-04-30 10:21:01"
            }
        ]
    } 

    this.player_IDs.forEach(function(value) {
      var id = value.toString();
      var endTime = playerdata.allplayers.filter(e => {
        if (e.Player_ID.includes(id)) {
          return e.End_Time;
        }
      });
      if (endTime.length != 0) {
        console.log(endTime);
      }
    });
```